# Where are the natural hot springs in Andalucia?

Tags: spain, nature-and-wildlife, andalusia

While browsing for a decent travel guide for Andalucia, I stumbled upon one that quite enthusiastically mentioned the existence of natural hot springs, close to Estepona. Albeit their penetrating smell, bading was supposed to be a real treat. I thought, I bought that specific guidebook, but unfortunately not.

Where are these hot springs located?

Comment: Andalucia is quite big and has more than one natural hot springs, could you improve your question so we can help you find what you are looking for?

Comment: @ivan the spring was supposed to be relatively close to estepona

Comment: These springs are not hot springs! Refreshing but not hot. About 20 degC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close to Estepona there are a roman baths called "Baños de la Hedionda" (stinky baths, literally). To get there you have to have your own vehicle or find a local transport to Manilva (it's the nearest village). From Manilva you can walk (there are [some interesting trekkings](http://es.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/view.do?id=6786113) around there) or go by car.

If you have a GPS go to: (WGS84) 36.396483  -5.2614660

If not, in Manilva, just ask for "Camino de los baños" (a nice paved road to the place you are looking for).

Please, note that usually the bathers don't use swim suit here, it's not officially a clothes optional place, but nobody cares about if you have or not your swimsuit. So be tolerant.

[image]